# how to submit form to custom php script in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

i have a custom script in app/library/custom.php...and i need to submit a form to this script via a post request, wondering how to do this in a laravel view - here is the form within the view

```
 <form class="jv-login-div" action="create_payment.php" method="post">
        <label for="jv-checkout-amount">Total Amount</label>
        <input type="text" id="jv-checkout-amount" name="amount" class="form-control₦ {{$amount}}</h5>
        <br/>
        <label for="jv-checkout-email">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="jv-checkout-email" name="email" class="form-control hidden" value="{{$email}}">
        <h5>{{$email}}</h5>
        <br/>

        @if($address)
        <label for="jv-checkout-address">Delivery Address</label>
        <input type="text" id="jv-checkout-address" name="address" class="form-control hidden" value="{{$address}}">
        <br/>
        <h5>{{$address}}</h5>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delivery" value="delivery"> Pay On Delivery<br>
        <button class="btn jv-btn pull-right" type="submit" role="button">continue</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: why don't you send it to a controller and load the library from there?

Comment: @Paul the custom script redirects to another url after doing some processing, how would i make the post request to the custom script from the controller?

Comment: you could for example send the form data back to the controller, and then pass the data to the library function

Comment: @paul thanks will try that